# Compute projected radii of a rotated elliptic paraboloid

Tags: quadrics

I'm working of a set of datapoints known to be an elliptic paraboloid on which I best fit the general quadric
$$ax²+bxy+cy²+dx+ey+f=0$$
Then I work with what I call radii projected on x an y defined as:
$$R_x=-\frac{1}{2a}, R_y=-\frac{1}{2c}$$

Now I have a dataset for which the rotational term $bxy$ is far from neglectable and I would like to compute $Rx'$ and $Ry'$ along the ellipsoid natural axes. How can I do that? I suppose I should rewrite equation with something like this?
$$u=x\cos \left(t\right)+y\sin \left(t\right)$$
$$v=x\sin \left(t\right)+y\cos \left(t\right)$$

Comment: How are you fitting a planar equation two a surface in 3-d?

Comment: I had the same question.  Rereading it, the data is projected into the $xy-$plane.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've projected onto the $xy-$plane where the underlying figure is an ellipse.

Write your equation defining the ellipse as

$$\begin{pmatrix} x & y \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a & \frac{b}{2} \\ \frac{b}{2} & c \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} d & e \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} +f=0 $$

Find the matrix $P$ that diagonalizes $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & \frac{b}{2} \\ \frac{b}{2} & c \end{pmatrix}$ so that

$$P^T A P = D.$$

Let $$\begin{pmatrix} x^\prime \\ y^\prime \end{pmatrix} = P \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$$

This gives new coordinates $(x^\prime, \, y^\prime)$ where the ellipse is in standard form.